# *t++ = *s++ ; String copy

Tags: string, pointers, copy, post-increment

This is a much discussed question however my doubt is that
in C, *t++ is equivalent to *(t++) as precedence of ++ (post increment operator) is greater than *. Therefore,in 
while (*t++ = *s++);
won't the first character be skipped while copying from s to t;
To frame it better, will the copy take place before the increment operator or afterwards and why?

Comment: You could write a test program and learn it for yourself...

Answer (score 2):

No, the first character won't be skipped. The result of evaluating `t++` (post-increment) is the value of `t` before the increment occurred, so the pointer dereference goes to the position pointed to before `t` was incremented. You can use the pre-increment operator (`++t`) to increment `t` and produce the value after the increment.